# Add value of cards - C

Tags: c

Working on a simple C programming question and I'm a bit stuck.

Q: Write a function that takes the values of a two-card blackjack HAND as input, and returns the point total of the hand. The value
 of the cards '2' through '9' is equal to their face value, the cards 'T', 'K', 'Q', 'J' are worth 10 points and the ace ('A') is worth 11 points
 unless it comes with another ace, then that second ace is worth 1 point. The program should be able to catch incorrect input.

Example:
Enter cards: T 7
The score is 17

Enter cards: A 5
 The score is 16

Note: I've used a value of 'T' for the 10 card so you can simply pass in two characters,
 instead of strings, as parameters to this function.

```
#define CASE_VALUE(str,val,card) case str: card = val;break;
int point_total(char card1,char card2){
  int card1_v;
  int card2_v;
  switch(card1){
    CASE_VALUE('2',2,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('4',4,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('5',5,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('6',6,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('7',7,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('8',8,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('9',9,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('T',10,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('K',10,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('Q',10,card1_v);
    CASE_VALUE('J',10,card1_v);
    default:
    return -1;
    break;
  }
   switch(card2){
    CASE_VALUE('2',2,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('3',3,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('4',4,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('5',5,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('6',6,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('7',7,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('8',8,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('9',9,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('T',10,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('K',10,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('Q',10,card2_v);
    CASE_VALUE('J',10,card2_v);
    default:
    return -1;
    break;
  }
  int value=card1_v+card2_v;
  return value;
  return -1;
}

// to test if it works
int main(void) {
    char card1 = 10;
    char card2 = 2;
    printf("%i\n", point_total(card1, card2));
    return 0;

}
```

Right now it is only returning -1, meaning the hand is invalid. I'm sure I'm overlooking something minor. I'm also unsure how to go about implementing the A (ace) card. Wondering if I'm on the right track and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you're sending `10` and `2` ... those do not match cases `'T'` and `'2'`. Do `char card1 = 'T';` etc. in main

Comment: What is the purpose of `point_total`? And what do you have to pass to it?

Comment: Goddness, how could I overlook that... 2. Point_total is suppose to take the values of a two-card blackjack hands as input and returns the point total of the hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is incorrect.

Also, there are several issues in your code (listed in decreasing severity order):

1. You are not passing '10' and '2' in the example but the ASCII characters which correspond to 10 and 2 (check the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/))
2. You are not considering the 'A' cases in your algorithm
3. `return -1;` after `return value;` is [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code)
4. You are writing everything twice (WET) which is a bad practice. This practice is the opposite of [don't repeat yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
5. The variables `int card1_v`, `int card2_v` are not necessary

The code can be improved by grouping the switch cases in different equivalence classes and using the decimal representation of the ASCII table values.

The following code is a correct implementation of the algorithm that you have described in your question, it also solves the problems that I previously pointed out. The comments explain the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculate_std_score(char card){
   /* use the ASCII decimal values to group ['2'...'9'] in the same equivalence class;
      shift the ASCII representation using '0' as "shifting value" to
      obtain the corresponding decimal representation. 
      Example: '2' is 50 in ASCII, '0' is 48 in ASCII;
                      return (50 - 48)*/
   if(49 < (int) card && (int) card < 58)
      return (card - '0');
   /* check for all the figures whose value is 10 */
   if(card == 'T' || card == 'J' || card == 'Q' || card == 'K')
      return 10;
   /* we already checked the particular case of (A,A);
       Now the card A can only have 11 as value */ 
   if(card == 'A')
      return 11;
   /* error: unrecognized character; we ensure to obtain always a negative sum */
   return -22;
}

int calculate_total_score(char card1, char card2){
  /* check (A,A) case : the ASCII decimal value of char 'A' is  65 */ 
  if((int) card1 + (int) card2 == 130)
     return 11;/* (A,A) = 10 + 1 */
  /* calculate the standard sum of the 2 card values */
  int result= calculate_std_score(card1) + calculate_std_score(card2);
  /* check erroneous result */ 
  if(result < 0)
     return -1;
  /* return standard result : no error detected */
  return result;
}

// to test if it works
int main(void) {
    char card1 = 'T';
    char card2 = '2';
    printf("%i\n", calculate_total_score(card1, card2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I'll study over your code and explanations so that I can improve.